# How could I convert this code into JAVASCRIPT string and eval it later?

Tags: javascript

I want to save this piece of js code and replace some strings and eval it later.
The problem I have is the I used online-converter but it doesn't work.

## Code

```
        $Lightning.use("c:app", function () {
                        $Lightning.createComponent("c:component",
                            {},
                            "customLogin",
                            function (cmp) {
                                console.log('test');
                            });
                    });
```

## Not working result

```
    var myvar = '$Lightning.use("c:app", function () {'+
    '                            $Lightning.createComponent("c:component",'+
    '                                {},'+
    '                                "customLogin",'+
    '                                function (cmp) {'+
    '                                    console.log(\'test\');'+
    '                                });'+
    '                        });';
```

Comment: "Not working" isn't very specific. What's happening? What is your expected result? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: remove the quotes, and do not treat that portion of code as a string

Comment: xy problem much? Just use variables, why would you replace it with strings

Comment: Why do you want to put code in a string? Put it into a *function* that you can *call* later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var myvar = $Lightning.use("c:app", function () {
    $Lightning.createComponent("c:component",
    {},
    "customLogin",
    function (cmp) {
        console.log('test');
    });
});
```